# lm function flipping order of interaction terms

Tags: r, lm

Suppose I run the following regression:

```
lm(mpg ~ wt+gear+cyl+cyl:wt+cyl:gear, data=mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt         gear          cyl       wt:cyl     gear:cyl  
    46.2774      -7.9976       1.6356      -2.2755       0.6852      -0.3135
```

As seen, the lm function automatically inverts the interaction terms in the output when the second interacted variable is included before: it names the regressors as "wt:cyl" and "gear:cyl", not as "cyl:wt" and "cyl:gear", as I inputed in the regression formula.

This is annoying to me because I later refer to the variable names to export the results. Is there a way to make the lm function keep the interaction terms in the order that you write the equation?

Comment: Why not write the interaction terms first?  `lm(mpg ~ cyl:wt+cyl:gear + wt + cyl + gear, data=mtcars)`

Comment: Your formula is equivalent to `lm(mpg ~ cyl*wt + cyl*gear, mtcars)`. And now `cyl` always comes first.

Comment: Any idea how to solve the problem if I did not want `cyl` as a standalone coefficient?